# Problem with retrofit to return generic Response

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I want to create a generic API call from a particular endpoint.
I have asynchronous tasks running on my server, my android application queries my server until the task is SUCCEEDED. I have different task results depending on the request, but the responses have common fields, only the result differs.
I would like to be able to retrieve the results with the generic API call.
Below is the code I implemented, the application builds correctly but I have an execption when it is executed.

Error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No JsonAdapter for T (with no annotations)

Codes

My data models:

```
abstract class TaskResult {
    var id: String = ""
    var status: String = "FAILURE"
}

data class GeoDataTaskResult(
    var result : GeoDataCollectionModel? = null
) : TaskResult() {}

data class OtherTaskResult(
    var result : OtherResultDataModel? = null
) : TaskResult() {}

...
```

Into APIService.kt:

```
@GET("tasks/{taskId}/result")
suspend fun <T> getAsyncTaskResult(
    @Header("Authorization") token: String,
    @Path("taskId") taskId: String
): Response<T>
```

Into ApiHelper.kt:

```
override suspend fun <T> getAsyncTaskResult(
    token: String,
    taskId: String
) : Response<T> = apiService.getAsyncTaskResult(token, taskId)
```

Into MainRespository.kt:

```
suspend fun <T> getAsyncTaskResult(
    token: String,
    taskId: String
) : Response<T> = apiHelper.getAsyncTaskResult(token, taskId)
```

Into MyViewModel.kt:

```
val result = mainRepository.getAsyncTaskResult<GeoDataTaskResult>(token, task_id)
```

I don't know if what I'm asking is possible or even correct

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can use okhttp3.ResponseBody as generic response type instead of T and call responseBody.string() to get the response as in string format. Then you can use json mapper(like Gson) to convert it into your desired Model class based on api calls.

Answer (score -1):

In your Interface

```
@GET("tasks/{taskId}/result")
suspend fun <T> getAsyncTaskResult(
    @Header("Authorization") token: String,
    @Path("taskId") taskId: String
): Response<T>
```

The response `T` is not defined as serialized data class.

Here is how to do it:

For example you are getting following json response

```
{
    "name": "Ghulam Rasul",
    "username": "~animator",
    "email": "hello@gmail.com",
    "contactNo": "+923154970584",
    "image": null,
    "gender": "Male"
}
```

Then its serialised data class will be:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class userdata(
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String,
    @SerializedName("username")
    val username: String,
    @SerializedName("email")
    val email: String,
    @SerializedName("contactNo")
    val contactNo: String,
    @SerializedName("image")
    val image: Any,
    @SerializedName("gender")
    val gender: String
)
```

And your interface should be:

```
@GET("tasks/{taskId}/result")
suspend fun <T> getAsyncTaskResult(
    @Header("Authorization") token: String,
    @Path("taskId") taskId: String
): Response<userdata>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but with your example I lose the generic side that I wish to have. User data is not generic. Normally T is "replaced" by GeoDataTaskResult on my example this is the behavior I would like to have.

Comment: Which is why `Error:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No JsonAdapter for T (with no annotations)` thrown at you. Every time you get a new type of response and there is no Serialised data class for that to convert that JSON response into something useable.